# Using perl, how do you process a regex taken from command line input?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm creating a script to take regex input from the command line and process it; something like this:

```
chomp(my $regex = $ARGV[0]);
my $name = '11528734-3.jpg';

$name =~ $regex;

print $name . "\n";
```

My input into the script is: "s/.jpg/_thumbnail.jpg/g"
but $name isn't processing the regex input from the command line.

Any advice on how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: You are doing a regex match but not checking whether it succeeded or using its results in any way.  What change to you want to happen to `$name`?

Comment: @ysth: I have a feeling that the OP had the argument in the form of `s/foo/bar/` and was expecting the `=~ $regex` to "expand" to `=~ s/foo/bar/`.

Comment: Now that you have added what your input is, your title/question is wrong. You are not trying to take a regex from the command line, you are trying to take an _operator_ from the command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `$name =~ $regex` won't change your `$name`. You have to use the `s///` operator to effect any change.

e.g.,

```
$name =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/;
```

If you are specifying *both* the pattern and replacement in the same argument, e.g., in the form of `s/foo/bar/`, you will have to split them first:

```
my (undef, $pattern, $replacement) = split '/', $regex;
$name =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/;
```

---

Original answer:

Use `qr//`:

```
$name =~ qr/$regex/;
```

You can also just use `$name =~ /$regex/`, but the `qr` version is more general, in that you can store the regex object for later use:

```
$compiled = qr/$regex/;
$name =~ $compiled;
$name =~ s/$compiled/foobar/;
```

etc.

Comment: shouldn't make any difference; just `=~ $regex` should work the same

Comment: @ysth: In that case, the OP's problem is that he's not using `s///`, and thus the string isn't modified. :-)

Comment: Splitting the string works, but is there any way ... besides maybe using eval ... to pull in whatever regex is sent into the script?
I updated the original question with my input into the script as well.